# How can I disable internet access on Windows 7 via the command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-connection

How can I easily disable (and later re-enable) internet access on Windows 7 via the command line (for an anti-procrastination script)? It would work fine if rebooting re-enables internet access. No local network access is required.

Comment: If it's anti-procrastination you're concerned with, then can I suggest physically unplugging the network cable and/or switching off the WIFI adapter. This works especially well if you have to get up from your chair to plug it back in....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also, disable the internet connection just by releasing the assigned IP address.

From the elevated command prompt (Run as administrator), type:

```
ipconfig/release
```

When you want to enable the internet connection then:

```
ipconfig/renew
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Try netsh:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection " ENABLE
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection " DISABLE
```

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows 8.1, though `ipconfig \release` did. Tried different combinations of the name, `Run as Administrator`, and so on. Nothing appeared to work. Recommend answer from @vernbutech.

Answer (score 0):

```
route delete -p 0.0.0.0
```

{shutdown}

```
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 <gataway ISP1> METRIC <METRIC 1> IF <interface number ISP1>
route add -p 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 <gataway ISP2> METRIC <METRIC 2> IF <interface number ISP2>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (win 7) these commands only work if I deleted the space before the second ".

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" ENABLE
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLE
```

I'm wondering if there is a command that can cut off all external connections but leave the wan and lan OK.

Comment: Huh? a WAN **is** the external connections.